# Linq within ASP.NET MVC controller syntax

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am very new to ASP.NET MVC so please be kind.

I have a very simple db with three tables Questions, QuestionOptions, Responses.

my pk in Questions is Id and links to questionId in both QuestionOptions and Responses. I also have a field in Questions called pageId, so multiple questions can appear on one page.

I started with this in my controller;

```
    // GET: /Questions/ViewQuestion/5
    public ActionResult ViewQuestion(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Question question = db.Questions.Find(id);
        if (question == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(question);
    }
```

And my View returns a single question and options perfectly;

```
@model Template.Models.Question

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}
<div>
    <h4>Question #@Model.questionId</h4>
    <hr />
<h1> @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.question1)</h1>
<ul>
    @foreach (var item in Model.QuestionOptions)
    {
        <li>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.questionOption1)</li>
    }
</ul>
```

But now I am trying to create a view that will display all of the questions with the same pageID - and am getting nowhere.

This is my new ActionResult;

```
        public ActionResult ViewQuestion(int? id)
    {
        var pageId = id;
        var question = from q in db.Questions
                       where q.pageId == pageId
                       orderby q.ranking
                       select new { q.questionId,
                       q.questionType, q.question1}
                       ;

        return View(question.ToList());
    }
```

And my View;

```
@model IEnumerable<Template.Models.Question>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "View question;";
}

<div>
    @foreach (var item in Model) {
    <h4>Question </h4>
    <hr />
    <h1> @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.question1.AsEnumerable())</h1>

    <ul>
        @foreach (var item in Model.QuestionOptions)
        {
            <li>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.questionOption1)</li>
    }
</ul>
}
```

But now it does not recognize `QuestionOptions` as part of the Model anymore, and even if I comment that section out I still get the error The model item passed into the dictionary is of type -- but this dictionary requires a model item of type `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`

I know somewhere my syntax is terribly wrong, but I have no idea where after searching for 3 days. Please help!

Comment: can you show us the Question model?

Comment: Your first example was return an object of type `Question`, but your second example is returning an anonymous type. Is this what you intended? You could just change your select to `select q`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your view you are expecting this model:
`@model IEnumerable<Template.Models.Question>`

but your model which you will get from your controller method is not of this type because you are returning a list of an anonymous type.

you need to change

```
var question = from q in db.Questions
               where q.pageId == pageId
               orderby q.ranking
               select new { q.questionId,
                            q.questionType, 
                            q.question1 };
```

into something like this:

```
var question = from q in db.Questions
               where q.pageId == pageId
               orderby q.ranking
               select new Template.Models.Question( )
                          { questionId = q.questionId,
                            questionType = q.questionType, 
                            question1 = q.question1 };
```

// EDIT:

I take another look into your code. In your method `ViewQuestion` you are returning the question which you get from your linq-query. So i think the `Model` you are using is 
not a special ViewModel. Instead you are passing the Edmx-model. You can do that but its not good practice. This query should work for you:

```
var questions = from q in db.Questions
                where q.pageId == pageId
                orderby q.ranking
                select q;
```

But you should think about creating your own class of `Question` where you only specify the values you need on the page and select them accordingly.

// EDIT2:

Just think about what you really need in your view and create a simple class which can hold this information. (This is a super simple case with no validation rules, etc.)

```
public class QuestionViewModel
{
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public string QuestionType { get; set; }
    public string QuestionText { get; set; }
    // datatypes are only a guess from me, you need to adapt them
}
```

don't forget to change the type in your view

```
@model IEnumerable<QuestionViewModel>
```

Comment: I am getting a new error: "The entity or complex type 'ProjectSiteModel.Question' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query."

Comment: And it still refuses to see Model.QuestionOptions as part of the Question model.. I would like to post the model for question but it is too long to include in a comment.

Comment: It seems that you have different types of the class `Question`. Try to specify `Template.Models.Question` instead of `ProjectSiteModel.Question`

Comment: I believe you have hit on my main problem - there is very little documentation on DB First. I am relying on the edmx. Can you please give me an example of what a viewModel for this scenario would be, please?

Comment: you have really inspired me. I am still having issues with this select, but your instructions made me take a good look at how to create ViewModels. Thanks a lot for helping.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a `Anonymous type` and not strongly typed which is  `Template.Models.Question` expected by view

Better change this to work for your Model based view

```
select new { q.questionId,
                       q.questionType, q.question1}
```

To

```
select new Template.Models.Question{ q.questionId,
                       q.questionType, q.question1}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I am supposed to do this, but as you've asked to see my Question class and it will not fit in a comment, I post it here. Please forgive me if this is a breech of etiquette.

```
namespace Template.Models
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class Question
{
    public Question()
    {
        this.QuestionOptions = new HashSet<QuestionOption>();
        this.Responses = new HashSet<Response>();
    }

    public int questionId { get; set; }
    public int eventId { get; set; }
    public int pageId { get; set; }
    public string question1 { get; set; }
    public int questionType { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> linkedTo { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> options { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ranking { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<QuestionOption> QuestionOptions { get; set; }
    public virtual QuestionType QuestionType1 { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Response> Responses { get; set; }
    }
}
```